# HTML5 Designed site - fixed button no longer staying fixed when viewed in Chrome and Opera

Tags: css, html, button

I designed the site susanadantas.com as a course project in April/14 and at the time of completion the "Book a Skin consultation today!" button was set to be positioned and function in the upper right area.  The site also passed validation in the W3C CSS and Markup.

I recently checked the site to see if everything was still functioning and in Chrome and Opera, just as the cursor nears the button, the button moves horizontally to the left.  It goes back to the correct position if the browser is refreshed.

I've searched for an answer and contacted my instructor hoping for some assistance but so far I'm still without an explanation or solution.

HTML5 Code:

```
<div><a href="contact.html"><img class="bookconsultbtn" src="images/button.png" width="230"    height="40" alt="Skin Consultation Button" /></a></div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.bookconsultbtn
{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 180px;

      -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  -webkit-transition:height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition:width 2s;
}   

.bookconsultbtn:hover
{
  box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgb(245, 130, 32);
  width: 240px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

http://susanadantas.com/Susana_Dantas/index.html

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this:

```
div#centeredonpage{position:relative}
.bookconsultbtn{top: 20px; right: 20px; /*or adjust at will */}
```

and voila, that button won't move anymore, you just need to define some coordinates for the position

Comment: Christine, if this is the correct answer please accept it

Comment: Hi Fabio and thank you.  I originally had this: div#centeredonpage
{ width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;}  and then added in the {position: relative} and then changed the next line of CSS.  Now the button doesn't move which is great but regardless of the numbers I enter for the position I can't get it to drop down just a tad so it's not right at the top and it won't move over to the right as far as I want it to.  There is also more space now between the bottom of the button and the top of the menu.

Comment: wait, you actually want it to move? about spacing, you'll need to adjust it to your taste, I placed this just as an example on how to do it, but the exact coordinates will depend on you as the designer. However, I'm wondering about the movement, because now I'm understanding you want it to move

Comment: Hi, no I don't want it to move.  I want it to stay in the upper right of each page.  It stays put now that I added your suggested {position: relative}.  But when I change the px for the top and right positioning of the button it won't locate where I want it to.  If I enter top: 10 and right: 200 and then change that to top: 40 and right: 400 it won't position where I want it to.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. No matter the number you enter, it will work, there's no way it won't move, it's simply impossible, so not sure if this is what you're asking. Just in case, are you sure you're adding px after the numbers?

Comment: Hi. Regardless of the number I enter with the px; the button will not move to the position I would like it to. For the top if I enter top: 10px; or top: 100px; it stays in the same location. The blank space between the bottom of the button and the top of the navigation also increases. So currently I have: div#centeredonpage
{
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;}  followed by: .bookconsultbtn
{
  top: 10px;
  left: 400px;
  
      -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  -webkit-transition:height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition:width 2s;
}

Comment: Christine, you're missing position: absolute; in .bookconsultbtn. It should be like this: `.bookconsultbtn{position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 400px; -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 / -webkit-transition:height 2s; / For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */ transition:width 2s;}` . I meant you to add it to what you had, hence the "add it" and "adjust at will", sorry if it was misunderstood

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood but it's working now in all browsers! I have div#centeredonpage
{
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}    and .bookconsultbtn
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 30px;
  
      -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  -webkit-transition:height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition:width 2s;
}   and it's perfect.  Thank you so much for your time and help!!!  I've only taken 2 HTML courses so I have a long, long way to go.